# T-SQL Convert String to Time for DATEDIFF() Calculation

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, reporting-services, ssms

I am having a problem converting a string to time in order to perform a DATEDIFF() calculation with another legitimate time field. My end goal is to create a report in SSRS.

The only way I have been able to perform this task in SSMS is by using:

```
,CAST(msdb.dbo.agent_datetime('19000101', P.[3]+'00') AS TIME(0)) AS [Reached Time]
```

P.[3] being a string field (Example value of 0744). I added the +'00' for milliseconds due to the format of "msdb.dbo.agent_datetime".

The above works perfectly in SSMS and gives a value of 07:44:00. However, this "msdb.dbo.agent_datetime" function will NOT work in SSRS. My report will only run if I remove any mention of "msdb.dbo.agent_datetime".

I need a different method to change this string value, such as 0744, to a legitimate time value of 07:44 or 07:44:00.

I have tried:

```
FORMAT(CONVERT(INT,P.[3]), 'HH:mm', 'en-us') --Returns value of HH:mm

CONVERT(VARCHAR, P.[3], 24) --Returns value of 0744

CONVERT(TIME, P.[3]) --Returns value of 00:00:00.0000000

CAST(P.[3] AS TIME) --Returns value of 00:00:00.0000000

CAST(CONVERT(INT,P.[3]) AS TIME) --Explicit conversion from data type int to time is not allowed.
```

Other combinations also error out. I have even tried to format the time in SSRS with no success.

I can make it look like a time by modifying the string, but then can't perform a calculation with DATEDIFF()

Please Help!

Answer (score 0):

I can't see any reason why you cannot use the function in your dataset query assuming permissions are correct for the credentials set against the datasource.

Anyway, to cheat you could recreate the function in you own database and use that version.

If you run the following in SSMS

```
USE msdb
exec sp_helptext 'dbo.agent_datetime'
```

You will get the script as follows,

```
CREATE FUNCTION agent_datetime(@date int, @time int)
RETURNS DATETIME
AS
BEGIN
 RETURN
  (
    CONVERT(DATETIME,
          CONVERT(NVARCHAR(4),@date / 10000) + N'-' + 
          CONVERT(NVARCHAR(2),(@date % 10000)/100)  + N'-' +
          CONVERT(NVARCHAR(2),@date % 100) + N' ' +        
          CONVERT(NVARCHAR(2),@time / 10000) + N':' +        
          CONVERT(NVARCHAR(2),(@time % 10000)/100) + N':' +        
          CONVERT(NVARCHAR(2),@time % 100),
    120)
  )
END
```

Use this to create the same function in your database.

Of course now, you see how simple the function is, you could create one that does the entire conversion in a single step.

Comment: Thanks, good suggestion, I'll try recreating it. Looking at that, I think the issue is SSRS doesn't know how to reference msdb by default where SSMS does.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me on SSMS:

```
declare @sourcetime char(4) = '1714'

select cast(left(@sourcetime, 2) + ':' + right(@sourcetime, 2) as datetime)
```